# Etale cohomology of a nodal (cuspidal) curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, decomposition-theorem

Let $k$ be a separably closed field, and $X/k$ be a curve (not necessarily complete) with a single singularity, a simple node $x$. Suppose $\ell$ is a prime number invertible in $k$, how do we compute the $\ell$ -adic cohomology of $X$?

My strategy is as follows, but there are several steps I am not sure.

First let us consider the case when $X$ is complete. Let $\pi: \widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be its normalization, then we have the exact sequence of etale sheaves on X:  $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \pi_*(\mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow F \rightarrow 0$ where $F$ is the quotient. By Prop 5.3.7 in Lei Fu's *Etale Cohomology* , the stalk of $\pi_*(\mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z})$ at $x$ is two copies of $\mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z}$ and one copy of $\mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z}$ elsewhere. So $F$ should be a constructible sheaf supported only on $x$, with stalk $\mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z}$, and its cohomology groups are clear: $H^0_{et}(X,F)=\mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z}$ and $0$ for other degrees.

But how do we compute the cohomology groups of $\pi_*(\mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z})$? For Zariski sheaf $F$ on $X$ and any affine morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$, we always have sheaf cohomology isomorphism $H^i(X,F)=H^i(Y,f_*F)$, by Cech cohomology. But for etale cohomology groups I don't know if this is right. If it is not, how do we compute $\pi_*(\mathbb{Z}/l^n\mathbb{Z})$'s cohomology?

My second difficulty is when $X$ is not complete. By Artin's vanishing theorem $H^2_{et}(X,Q_{\ell})=0 $. And we can embed $X$ into a compactification $\overline{X}$, and expect there are some relations between cohomology of $X,\overline{X},\overline{X}-X$. Usually, we can use Gysin sequence to compute the cohomology for a smooth pair $(X, Y)$, where both $X,Y$ are smooth and $Y$ is a closed subscheme of $X$. In all the materials I read, the Gysin sequence requires both $X$ and $Y$ are smooth, but in my case they are not. Does Gysin sequence still hold?

What if $X$ has a single cusp?

Comment: First question: It's ok because $\pi$ is finite, since pushforward along a finite morphism is an exact functor for etale sheaves. Second question: There's a version of the Gysin sequence where $X$ is only smooth in a neighborhood of $Y$, but maybe it's easier to apply the Gysin sequence to the normalization and then push forward along the normalization map.

Comment: @WillSawin I found prop 5.7.4 on Lei Fu‘s book one minute after I posted this question. Thanks for your reply! That’s very helpful!